# How do I add a dynamic base template in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have a base.html template. In the base.html template contains the menu bar, the fixed footer and the content block.
Exemple:

**base.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2" href="/">
            <img src="{{ url of an image added in the database that can be changed by the user }}" height="60" class="d-inline-block" alt="site">Site</a>
        <button class="btn btn-link bd-search-docs-toggle d-md-none p-0 ml-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Diário Oficial do PL</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Site Oficial do PL</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Links Úteis</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="container" style="min-height: calc(100vh - 230px);">
{% block content %}
<!-- Blocl content -->
{% endblock %}
</div>
{% block footer %}
{% endblock %}
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block conteudo %}
<p>Content bla bla bla bla bla </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Orgao(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    logo = models.ImageField()
```

How would a view that would take this image in the database and show in the base.html that is extended to all the pages of the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use get_context_data in every view.
There is such thing as a context processor in django, it's made specifically to deliver context to every page of the web app.
So, in your case that would be:

```
# context_proccesors.py

from .models import Orgao

def orgao_logo(request):
    orgao = Orgao.objects.filter(name='somename') # or whatever object you need
    return {'logo':orgao.logo}
```

Then you need to add this context proccessor to your settings.py:

```
#settings.py

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    ....
                    'context_processors.orgao_logo',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

And finaly you can use it in your templates via the context keyword:

```
<img src="{{logo.url}}">
```

Comment: Impressive. That's exactly what I needed. I did not know. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: where i create  context_proccesors.py file in app folder or in project folder?

Comment: @BInjalPatel the convention is to create `context_proccesors` folder on the same level as manage.py file. In that folder you put your `some_proccesor.py` file. Then you reference it in the `settings.py` like `'context_proccesors.some_proccesor'`, as show in my answer.

Comment: i got error like this:`ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'context_processors'`

Comment: @BInjalPatel put  empty `__init__.py` in `context_proccesors` folder. And make sure that folder is in the root of the project

Comment: i create `context_proccesors` folder on the same level as `manage.py` file. In this folder i put  `context_proccesors.py` file. In this file i put  `category_get` function. In setting.py, how to write reference of that function in setting.py?

Comment: @BInjalPatel `'context_processors.context_processors.category_get'`. And put empty `__init__.py` file in the context_processors folder! Otherwise Django won't register module.

Comment: i got this error : ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'context_proccesors.models'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193092/discussion-between-bloodwithmilk-and-binjal-patel).

Answer (score 1):

You could include the image url in the context you're returning for each view. For exemple you could use the short function [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

You could also use a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) to return the url directly in the template

Comment: That way every time I create a new page, I would have to add the tag to the template, or a view to render the image for each created page. I would like to do this only once, regardless of the page size. Is there any way to render the image to the base, and all pages that are extended from base.html, inherit this image?

Comment: You could create a simple tag, (or an inclusion tag if you also need to render something), and add it to "base.html"